# why would [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] return 0?

Tags: iphone, retina-display

I thought I was doing something relatively simple, but I guess not.

Running:

```
NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

returns 0.000000

The problem is that I am trying to check for a retina display and the:

```
if([UIScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] &&
   [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
    // does not get called on an iPhone 4
}
```

Doesnt get called. I have tried this both in the simulator as well as on the device.

Comment: Where are calling your code from?

Comment: it's in a subclass of UIView that displays tiles for a CATiledLayer

Comment: i also just tried moving it to viewDidLoad in my main viewController and it still returned 0.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is [How to call [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] in a universal app for the iphone and ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130420/)